# memory error adding large csr matrics

Tags: python, matrix, addition, csr

I'm not sure if this has been discussed before, so let me open up a thread on this:

I'm getting a memory error when adding large csr matrices. I wrote an recursive approximation of the matrix exponential applied on another matrix V, i.e. exp(-i H t)V using a Taylor series:

```
import gc
def my_expm(H,V):
  v = V
  i = 1
  gc.collect()
  while i <= 60:
        v = -1j/i*H.dot(v)
        gc.collect()
        V += v
        gc.collect()
        print i
        i += 1
  return V
```

where H is a sparse csr square matrix of type np.real_64 and V is a square sparse (csr) matrix of type np.complex_128. Both have the same size ~ 8000x8000.

I am getting the following MemoryError:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TFI.py", line 224, in <module>
  UF = my_expm(t*H,UF)
File "TFI.py", line 202, in my_expm
  V += v
File "~/.conda/envs/exact_diag/lib/python2.7/site-    
packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 351, in __add__
  return self._binopt(other,'_plus_')
File "~/.conda/envs/exact_diag/lib/python2.7/site-  
packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 1103, in _binopt
  data = np.empty(maxnnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
MemoryError
```

What's really puzzling me is that the error in the line `V+=v` does not happen at the first iteration, but rather at the i=6 sixth one. This suggests to me that there is still a way to free some memory on the fly and make the script work.

Moreover, if I get rid of the line `V+=v` then I get no memory error, although memory has been allocated for all the matrices used in the loop.

The gc.collect() trick is supposed to clear the memory each time it is called, but I think it doesn't really do much.

Let me say that I have also tried with matrices of type np.complex_64 but the error was the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem that at some point the matrix is being converted from sparse to dense?  At the point it becomes quite chunky.

Comment: This may very well be. But since I've localised the error to the line `V+=v` I would assume that scipy can add matrices without turning them to dense first.